# Positioning the jQuery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm using jQuery modal form dialog to prompt user for few quick option selections. Basically, it's a table listing all users and one of the columns has two links:

1. to initiate Archiving all user files
2. to initiate Archiving only files uploaded since last archive.

Whatever the link user clicks a modal form dialog appears asking user about including only original files or original+small thumbnails or original+small+large thumbnails.

Everything works fine except that the dialog loads at the bottom of the page thus spoiling the user experience. Basically, I would like the dialog to appear closer to the row on which user clicked. Dialog is `open`ed from the click event, btw. Any insights?

Dialog is loaded with the following options:

```
autoOpen: false,
  height: 200,
  width: 400,
  modal: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the API documentation to adjust the position of the dialog based on your needs:

> http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

The default parameters are:

> { my: "center", at: "center", of: window }

Example usage:

```
 $( ".selector" ).dialog({ position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: button } });
```

For more precise positioning, please refer to [this page.](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/)

```
$( "#position3" ).position({
  my: "right center",
  at: "right bottom",
  of: "#targetElement"
});
```

Comment: I was stuck with appendTo. Thanks for the hint. I'm trying the position.

Comment: Impressed! Works like a charm. My next stop is the positioning page. Need to understand this a bit more. Thank you so much for such a quick reply. It was so quick that I have to wait few more minutes before calling it an answer! :)